# show the form response in modal window using Magnific Popup

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, popup

I am trying to submit a form using ajax and show the response on modal window using Magnific Popup. I have posted the code below. In regarding to make it work I have to click "send" button then "popup" button. I was playing with for the last 3 hours and couldn't make it work. Can you please see what I am doing wrong? I want to click to send button and see the php responses on the modal popup window.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/dimsemenov/Magnific-Popup/master/dist/jquery.magnific-popup.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
 jQuery(document).ready(function() {

               $(document).on('click', '.popup-modal', function (e) {

                $( "#indexform" ).on( "submit", function( event ) {
              event.preventDefault();
              var formdata = $(this).serialize();
              $.ajax({
                    type:"POST",
                    url:"result.php",
                    data:formdata,
success: function(msg){
            $("#modal-results").html(msg)

        },
        error:function(){
            alert("failure");
        }
              });
            });


    });

    $('.popup-modal').magnificPopup({
    type: 'inline'

});
            });
</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://rawgit.com/dimsemenov/Magnific-Popup/master/dist/magnific-popup.css">
    <style>
    div#modal-results {
    color: white;
}
</style>
</head>  
<body>
                <form method="post" name="index" id="indexform">
                <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="NAME">
                <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="EMAIL">
                <textarea rows="3" name="message" placeholder="MESSAGE"></textarea>
                <input name="sendData" type="submit" value="SEND">
                <button  type="submit" class="popup-modal" href="#modal-results">Popup</button>
                <div id="modal-results"></div>
                </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: call `$('.popup-modal').magnificPopup({...` after document is loaded wiht `$(document).ready()` function as described in [documentation](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/documentation.html). Search for "Initializing popup". The element `.popup-modal` probably is't loaded yet, when you are trying to initialize the pop-up.

Comment: you are not seting it correctly, based on documentation for ["inline type"](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/documentation.html#inline-type). You have to set items paramater that contains `type` and `src`. See my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are not seting it correctly, based on documentation for ["inline type"](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/documentation.html#inline-type). You have to set items paramater that contains `type` and `src`.

I created a function createSrc that is called when button is pressed. It creates an `<div>` element that is used for modal dialog. I also added the style for this window.

```html
<html>
    <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://rawgit.com/dimsemenov/Magnific-Popup/master/dist/jquery.magnific-popup.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript">
     jQuery(document).ready(function() {

                   $(document).on('click', '.popup-modal', function (e) {

                    $( "#indexform" ).on( "submit", function( event ) {
                  event.preventDefault();
                  var formdata = $(this).serialize();
                  $.ajax({
                        type:"POST",
                        url:"result.php",
                        data:formdata,
    success: function(msg){
                $("#modal-results").html(msg)

            },
            error:function(){
                alert("failure");
            }
                  });
                });


        });

        $('.popup-modal').magnificPopup({
        items: {
          src: createSrc(),
          type: 'inline'
      }

    });
});
       
function createSrc(){
        return "<div class='white-popup'>" + jQuery("#name").val() + "<br>" + "</div>";
}
    </script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://rawgit.com/dimsemenov/Magnific-Popup/master/dist/magnific-popup.css">
        <style>
        div#modal-results {
        color: white;
    }

    .white-popup {
      position: relative;
      background: #FFF;
      padding: 20px;
      width: auto;
      max-width: 500px;
      margin: 20px auto;
    }

    </style>
    </head>  
    <body>
                    <form method="post" name="index" id="indexform">
                    <input id="name" type="text" name="name" placeholder="NAME">
                    <input id="email" type="text" name="email" placeholder="EMAIL">
                    <textarea id="message" rows="3" name="message" placeholder="MESSAGE"></textarea>
                    <input name="sendData" type="submit" value="SEND">
                    <button  type="submit" class="popup-modal" href="#modal-results">Popup</button>
                    <div id="modal-results"></div>
                    </form>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

**EDIT**

Since you are using ajax, you don't need `<form>` tag. I modified your friends code. You were also duplicting POST request calls. Fist click didn't do a POST request and so couldnt show an error, because you rewrote it when you initalized the popup. The second click got 1 POST request, the third click sent 2 POST requests, the forth 3 and so on.

Try the code below:

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/dimsemenov/Magnific-Popup/master/dist/jquery.magnific-popup.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">

 jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    $( '.popup-modal').on('click', function(e) {
          
         console.log( $(this).serialize() );
            var formdata = $(this).serialize();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "http://demo.sbvan.com//result.php",
                data: formdata,
                success: function(msg) {
                    $("#modal-results").html(msg);
                    $('.popup-modal').magnificPopup({
                          type: 'inline'
                     });

                },
                error: function() {
                    $("#modal-results").html("failure");
                    $('.popup-modal').magnificPopup({
                          type: 'inline'
                     });
                }
            });      


    });

});
   
</script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://rawgit.com/dimsemenov/Magnific-Popup/master/dist/magnific-popup.css">
    <style>
    div#modal-results {
    color: white;
}
</style>
</head>  
<body>
                
                <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="NAME">
                <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="EMAIL">
                <textarea rows="3" name="message" placeholder="MESSAGE"></textarea>
                <!--<input name="sendData" type="submit" value="SEND">-->
                <button  class="popup-modal" href="#modal-results">Popup</button>
                <div id="modal-results"></div>
                
</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT 2:**

You can also create pop-up with funciont, without button. So call that function after you click on submit. But remember, you are not using any ACTION tag in your form so there is no need to have your input type "submit". Set it ot "button" instead. You are submiting it via AJAX.

```
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/dimsemenov/Magnific-Popup/master/dist/jquery.magnific-popup.js"></script> 

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://rawgit.com/dimsemenov/Magnific-Popup/master/dist/magnific-popup.css">
    <style>
    .white-popup {
      position: relative;
      background: #FFF;
      padding: 20px;
      width: auto;
      max-width: 500px;
      margin: 20px auto;
    }
    #popup {
        visibility: hidden;     
    }

</style>
</head>  
<body>
                <form method="post" name="index" id="indexform">
                <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="NAME"><br/>
                <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="EMAIL"><br/>
                <textarea rows="3" name="message" placeholder="MESSAGE"></textarea><br/>
                <input name="sendData" id="sendData" type="button" value="SEND">                
                <div id="modal-results" class="white-popup mfp-hide">
                <p><a class="popup-modal-dismiss" href="#">Dismiss</a></p>
                </div>
                </form>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    jQuery(document).ready(function() {

                        $( '#sendData').on('click', function(e) {

                                console.log( $(this).serialize() );
                                var formdata = $(this).serialize();
                                $.ajax({
                                    type: "POST",
                                    url: "result.php",
                                    data: formdata,
                                    success: function(msg) {
                                        $("#modal-results").html(msg);
                                       $.magnificPopup.open({
                                        items: {
                                            src: '#modal-results',
                                            type: 'inline'

                                        }
                            });

                                    },
                                    error: function() {
                                        $("#modal-results").html("failour");
                                        $.magnificPopup.open({
                                            items: {
                                                src: '#modal-results',
                                                type: 'inline'

                                            }
                                        });
                                    }
                                });      


                        });

                    });
                </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I uploaded it to http://demo.sbvan.com/test.html as it is not working on jsfiddle because of the result.php file. As you can see on the test page I can submit the values and I can see the values on the console but the modal window doesn't show the php results. On the other hand my friend sent this solution http://demo.sbvan.com/test2.html first time when popup button is clicked nothing happens when the second time is clicked the responses from the php file appears on the modal window. Any idea why it is not showing the error messages on the modal window when the button first time is clicked?

Comment: can you see http://demo.sbvan.com/test3.html please? Still doesn't seem to be working.  I have uploaded Erdem's post to http://demo.sbvan.com/test4.html and it is seems to be working. It still has two buttons though. I liked your last code should work but somethinh is missing.

Comment: Thanks. Nomeaning25. It's working but I still have two buttons and I couldn't make to remove the values after submit.  placed   $('form')[0].reset(); after success but it removes in every time I press send button it should only reset the form and successfull submit not when therefield is missing.

Comment: Been reading the forums. You can itnitalize your popup via jQuery with `$.magnificPopup.open({
            items: {
                src: '#modal-results',
                type: 'inline'

            }
        });`

Comment: woaww thank you works great removed the second button.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/dimsemenov/Magnific-Popup/master/dist/jquery.magnific-popup.js"></script> 

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://rawgit.com/dimsemenov/Magnific-Popup/master/dist/magnific-popup.css">
    <style>
    .white-popup {
   position: relative;
   background: #FFF;
   padding: 20px;
   width: auto;
   max-width: 500px;
   margin: 20px auto;
 }
 #popup {
  visibility: hidden;  
 }

</style>
</head>  
<body>
                <form method="post" name="index" id="indexform">
                <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="NAME"><br/>
                <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="EMAIL"><br/>
                <textarea rows="3" name="message" placeholder="MESSAGE"></textarea><br/>
                <input name="sendData" type="submit" value="SEND">
                <button  type="submit" id="popup" class="popup-modal" href="#modal-results">Popup</button>                
                <div id="modal-results" class="white-popup mfp-hide">
    <p><a class="popup-modal-dismiss" href="#">Dismiss</a></p>
    </div>
                </form>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                 $("#indexform").submit(function(event) {
              event.preventDefault();
              var formdata = $(this).serialize();
              $.ajax({
                  type: "POST",
                  url: "result.php",
                  data: formdata,
                  success: function(msg) {
                      $("#modal-results").html(msg);
                  },
                  error: function() {
                      $("#modal-results").html("Failure");
                  }

              }).done(function() {
                  $('.popup-modal').magnificPopup({
                      type: 'inline'

                  });
                  $('#popup').click();
              });
           });
                </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: works great. thank you. http://demo.sbvan.com/test4.html this is the working demo. Would be good if there was only one button.